# JavaScript Weather App. I want to change the temp from C to F when you click on it. It's not working

Tags: javascript, html, weather, openweathermap, weather-api

It works perfectly fine when the location is detected by browser (using latitude and longitude by allowing location) and toggles well. It's not working when I fetch details of temperature of the city using API it toggles only once for some cities. For some cities it works fine and for some cities it only shows in Fahrenheit.

```js
let loc =document.getElementById("location");
let tempicon=document.getElementById("temp-icon");
let tempvalue=document.getElementById("temp-value");
let climate =document.getElementById("climate");
let iconfile;
let tempunit = document.getElementById("temp-unit");
let tempSection=document.querySelector('.temp-section');
const searchInput=document.getElementById("search-input");
const searchButton=document.getElementById("search-button");

//Accept the City
searchButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>
{

e.preventDefault();
getWeather(searchInput.value);
searchInput.value='';

});

//Celsius to Fahrenheit
function celsiusToFahrenheit (temperature){
    return (temperature *9/5)+32;
}


// for any particular city
const getWeather=async (city)=>
{
    try{

        const response= await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid={key}`,
   
            {mode: 'cors'}
        );

        const weatherData= await response.json();
        console.log(weatherData);
        const{name}=weatherData;
        const{feels_like}=weatherData.main;
        const{id,main}=weatherData.weather[0];
        loc.textContent=name;
        climate.textContent=main;
        tempvalue.textContent=Math.round(feels_like-273).toFixed(2);
        
        tempSection.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(tempunit.textContent === "°C"){
                let fahrenheit = (celsiusToFahrenheit(feels_like-273)).toFixed(2);
                tempunit.textContent="F";
                tempvalue.textContent=fahrenheit;
            }else{
                tempunit.textContent="°C";
                tempvalue.textContent=(feels_like-273).toFixed(2);   
            }
            
        });
        
    }
catch(error)
{
    alert('city not found');
}

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Weather app</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="../assets/css/Weather_app.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="search-form">
            <input type="search"
            placeholder="Enter City Name"
            id="search-input"
            required
            autocomplete="off"
            />
            <br>
        </br>
        <button id="search-button">Search</button>

        </form>


        <main id="app-container">
            <div id="location">
                <p>-------</p>
            </div>
                <div id="temp">
                    <img id="temp-icon" src="../assets/Images/weather_icons/sun.svg" alt="">
                    <div class="temp-section"><span id="temp-value">-----</span> <span id="temp-unit" >°C</span> </div>
                </div>

                <div id="climate">
                    <p>------</p>
                </div>
        </main>

<script src="../assets/js/Weather_app.js">

</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units.
Wind speed is available in miles/hour and meter/sec.

For temperature in Fahrenheit and wind speed in miles/hour, use units=imperial
For temperature in Celsius and wind speed in meter/sec, use units=metric
Temperature in Kelvin and wind speed in meter/sec is used by default, so there is no need to use the units parameter in the API call if you want this

ex : units=imperial

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=39.92077&lon=32.85411&units=imperial&lang=tr&exclude=&appid=xxxxxx
```